# sistema de autentificación en laravel

Tags: laravel, base-de-datos, autenticación

como hago para autentificar a usuarios en laravel. teniendo en cuenta lo siguiente. Que el usuario registrado se encuentra en diferentes bases de datos, es decir un usuario1 esta registrado en un sistema1 y con un motor de bases de datos "mysql", y otro usuario2 esta registrado en otro sistema2 y con motor de bases de datos "postgresql",y otro usuario3 esta registrado en otro sistema3 y con motor de bases de datos "sqlserver", me entendieron ??.
Un sistema que autentifique a los usuarios que se encuentran en tres diferentes sistemas con diferentes motores de base de datos.
Eso se puede ?

Answer (score 1):

Si es posible, te invito [a leer este artículo en Styde](https://styde.net/multiples-bases-de-datos-con-laravel-5-y-eloquent/) o [este otro en Cristalab](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/como-usar-multiples-bases-de-datos-en-laravel-c113373l/)

Saludo!

Comment: muchas gracias amigo lo vere :D

Comment: sabes ya lei los articulos que me mencionaste pero sabe aun no encuentro la solucion a mi problema ya que al usar diferentes motores de bases de datos tengo que especificar las credenciales. de otros motores,

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=prueba
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Comment: Hola @Rudy 
En tu archivo `config\database.php` puedes añadir múltiples conexiones según tus necesidades. [Styde](https://styde.net/multiples-bases-de-datos-con-laravel-5-y-eloquent/) lo ejemplifica en su post. Saludos!